# Function parameter as this.variable

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and would like to use one method for multiple things:

```
data: {
    genders: [],
    months: [],
}

methods: {
    getModels:function(cat,model) {
        $.getJSON('/api/models/' + cat + '/' + model, function(data) {
            this.model = data;
        }.bind(this));
    },
},

created: {
    this.getModels('core', 'genders');
    this.getModels('core', 'months');
},
```

In the method I want to be able to select the correct array with the data that has been fetched. But the code is instead looking for the 'model' data when I need it to look for the 'genders' and 'months' data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access to some data by its name, you should do

```
model = 'genders' // just to ilustrate the example
this[model] = data
```

because `this.model` is equal to `this['model']`, and in the above code, `this[model]` is equal to `this['genders']` or `this.genders`